# Abrir uma imagem recebida por um banco de dados online

Tags: android, imageview

Eu recupero a imagem do banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
btm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imgView.setImageBitmap(btm);
```

E então eu coloco uma ação para ao clicar na imagem apareça a imagem no visualizador padrão do Android.

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent1.setDataAndType(**"Tenho que colocar algo aqui"**, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
```

Ou como eu poderia após recuperar a imagem colocar ela para abrir no visualizador da galeria.

Comment: Filho, você está no *SOpt* traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Já modifiquei a publicação!

Comment: Você somente vai conseguir exibir na galeria, se o arquivo estiver baixado no dispositivo. Como pelo seu código o mesmo só está no ImageView, crie uma view/activity/fragment e exiba da maneira que achar melhor. Inclusive existem alguns componentes de ImageView que já tem zoom implementado